# How do I add (sum of numbers) within a data-table in ajax even if a new row is added with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to make an addition (or subtraction if needed) to a php page with ajax.

What this code is supposed to do is add all the prices up and give me the correct sum with the live-edit-table.

if a user changes the value of price $price_total should change acordingly.

Even if a new row is added it should still give the new sum (displayed in $price_total and $final_price_total) with the new row included.

I have been trying to figure out how to do this but I can't figure out how.

$price_total and $final_price_total do not get saved into a database

this is the code that I have so far:

index.php

```
<html>
      <head>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
           <div class="container">
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="table-responsive">
                     <div id="live_data"></div>            
                </div>
           </div>
      </body>
 </html>
 <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    function fetch_data(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"select.php",
            method:"POST",
            success:function(data){
                $('#live_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    function formatDecimal(val, n) {
        n = n || 2;
        var str = "" + Math.round ( parseFloat(val) * Math.pow(10, n) );
        while (str.length <= n) {
            str = "0" + str;
        }
        var pt = str.length - n;
        return str.slice(0,pt) + "." + str.slice(pt);
    }

    fetch_data();
    function edit_data(id, text, column_name){
        $.ajax({
            url:"edit.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                id:id,
                text:text,
                column_name:column_name
            },
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                /*alert(data);*/
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){
        /* this function would also add the prices to the table*/ 
        var price = $('#price').text();
        var final_price = $('#final_price').text();
        if(price == ''){
            alert("Enter Price");
            return false;
        }
        if(final_price == ''){
            alert("Enter Final Price");
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{price:price, final_price:final_price},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                fetch_data();
            }
        })
    });

    $(document).on('blur', '.price', function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id1");
        var price = $(this).text();
        edit_data(id, price, "price");
        /*I'm trying so that I can add the new input price with the old total to give the exact value*/
        $total = parseFloat( price ) + parseFloat( $('#price_total').value );
        $('#price_total').value = formatDecimal(total);
    });

    $(document).on('blur', '.final_price', function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id2");
        var final_price = $(this).text();
        edit_data(id, final_price, "final_price");
    });


});
```

select.php

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_db");  
$output = '';  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sample ORDER BY id DESC";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

$output .= '
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
    <th width="10%">Id</th>
    <th width="40%">Price</th>
    <th width="40%">Final Price</th>
    <th width="10%">Delete</th>
    </tr>';
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $final_price_total = 0;
    $price_total = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
            <td class="price" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["price"].'</td>
            <td class="final_price" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["final_price"].'</td>
            <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>
            </tr>
            ';
            $final_price_total += $row["final_price"];
            $price_total += $row["price"];
        }
        $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="price_total" id="price_total" name="price_total" value="'.$price_total.'" contenteditable>'.$price_total.'</td>
            <td class="final_price_total" id="final_price_total" name="final_price_total" value="'.$final_price_total.'" contenteditable>'.$final_price_total.'</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            ';
        $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id="price" contenteditable></td>
            <td id="final_price" contenteditable></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>
            </tr>
            ';
}
else{
    $output .= '<tr>
    <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>
    </tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>
</div>';
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Does insert.php complete successfully? Any error logs in the php log?

Comment: yes, everything works, but `$(document).on('blur', '.price', function(){` to update the cell when there is a change in the number

Comment: Okay, that wasn't clear from your question :). Please describe the behaviour that the current code is doing wrongly.

Comment: edit, insert and delete work correctly. The only thing that does not work is the 'update sum of values' after a change in any cell value. Don't know if this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

From the little discussion in the question comments, I've managed to spot this variable typo:

```
 $total = parseFloat( price ) + parseFloat( $('#price_total').value );
 $('#price_total').value = formatDecimal(total);
```

On the second line you are using `total` instead of `$total`.

If you check your browser's error console, you will see an error about undeclared variable `total`.

Edit: after further discussion, you wanted to know how to loop over the table in JavaScript and add up the total. Try this:

```
var newTotal = 0.0;
$('.price').each(function() {
    newTotal += parseFloat($(this).text());
});
```

If you do this on your edit finding, you can then use the newTotal variable in the final_price field in place of where you are using the $total variable.

Comment: the problem in that is the reverse of what you said. Should be `total = parseFloat( price ) + parseFloat( $('#price_total').value );` but still does not fix the problem, thanks for pointing this out though

Comment: Two approaches: 1) loop over the whole table's prices and add them together or 2) keep a history of the old price before updating it, subtract it from the total and then add the new price as it is currently doing. Option 1 is more tolerant of network issues when editing multiple rows.

Comment: I already loop through all the prices and add them together but the problem comes after when the data changes and the sum has to change

Comment: Sorry I meant do it after the new price has been edited, in JavaScript. I suppose the ajax request to save the edit could do a query to SUM the price fields and return that, but you have all the data on the page already.

Comment: how would I do this?